# How to use vlookup to check the data i need and gives me the value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the dataset with values, i Need that vlookup function gives me a value based on criteria that i set. 
For example:
i Need all the prognose values of the series Name NGA based on the Date production. 
I have constructed somehow the dataset so it could be more clear.

`=VLOOKUP(F3&N$1;$A$2:$I$500;9;TRUE)`

i want that in NGA column  that are only the prognose of NGA inside  based on the date column [Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00mQm.png)

The expected values to be in this way [Expected values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zXu3.png)

Comment: It's not very clear tbh. Can you include you expected result? What is the value of `F3`? Do you want to return a full list or just a value. You mention both options in your question.

Comment: The value F3 is the date, and based on that date and the Name of the Series (NGA) i want the prognose in the column named NGA.

Comment: Right, but you still havent mentioned if your expected result is just a value, or a full list?

Comment: yeah sorry, i was just about to edit. yeah i want all the list. i will upload a Pictures so you can see it.

Comment: You expect a bunch of errors? Please see [ask] a question with a [mcve] and be clear about your sample data and expected result. Instead of your own attempted formula, type the values your expect to see there. It's hard to help you otherwise.

Comment: it should be more clear now, i add it @JvdV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me what you described and show through your sample data can be achieved through:

```
=IF($D2=K$1,$G2;"")
```